# Oracle: Where do I keep the config settings?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have three Oracle 11g databases: develop, test and production. Suppose the logging directory is different on the three systems:

```
dev  => \var\log\oracle\
test => e:\logging\
prod => g:\logs\logging\
```

I'm using these directories with utl_file.

Where do I keep these settings? Is there some kind of 'ora_config.ini' where I store these values and read them easily with PL/SQL?

Comment: In this case you shouldn't use a config file for these differences between environments but a real Oracle object called a directory. See my answer.

Comment: So I should just keep those three scripts out of my VCS? And just ask the other developers to execute the script on their own machine as well?

Comment: Yes. The DBA should create these objects -- and grants on them -- just once. Let me repeat what I wrote in my answer: *Don't* grant permission to create directory objects to just any database user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since at least Oracle 9i, Oracle has a `directory` object. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_5007.htm

You should create a directory object with the same name on each of your systems, and refer to that directory by name in your calls to `utl_file`.

For example, on "dev":

```
create directory logging_dir as '/var/log/oracle';
```

On "test":

```
create directory logging_dir as 'e:\logging';
```

On "prod":

```
create directory logging_dir as 'g:\logs\logging';
```

And your PL/SQL code is identical in all environments, eg:

```
f := utl_file.fopen('LOGGING_DIR', 'filename.log', 'W');
```

The DBA should create the directory objects and grant permissions to the database users or roles needing to use them.

*Don't* grant system privilege to create directory objects to just any database users as this is creating security holes by allowing Oracle to read or possibly write anywhere on the filesystem as the OS user "oracle".

Comment: My question was not clear enough. I' really want to keep all the code in my version control system, except the 'hard coded' part. So I would end up with something like:

    create directory logging_dir as '$some_variable';

Where is the best place to store $some_variable?

Comment: Installation instructions? These directory objects should be created just once, just like the physical directory is created just once.